# Is there a way to see if a string contains any symbols in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't mean specific characters, I just mean anything that isn't alphanumeric. I've tried asking if the string contains only alphabetic and numeric characters like so:

```
if userInput.isalpha() and userInput.isdigit() == False:
    print ("Not valid, contains symbols or spaces")
```

but this doesn't work and and denies all passwords I put in.

Comment: Your condition checks if `isalpha` and **not** a digit.

Comment: Leo, don't forget to select an answer as correct to help those looking at this question in the future.

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, you can't be only alpha and only numeric, so your expression will always be false.

Secondly the methods `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` equate to `True` or `False`, so no need to use `== False`.

I would suggest using `.isalnum()`.

If that doesn't satisfy you're requirements you should use a regex.

`alnum` looks for both: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum and works in Python 3.x and 2.

Example:

```
>>> 'sometest'.isalnum()
True
>>> 'some test'.isalnum()
False
>>> 'sometest231'.isalnum()
True
>>> 'sometest%231'.isalnum()
False
>>> '231'.isalnum()
True
```

Answer (score 7):

You have three problems:

- `if a and b == False` is **not** the same is `if a == False and b == False`;
- `if b == False` should be written `if not b`; and
- You aren't using [`str.isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum), which saves you from the problem anyway.

So it should be:

```
if not userInput.isalnum():
```

Comment: @Scironic I'm a little surprised by them myself!